# Do I need to know C# to program with Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've learnt just a few basic programs in C# but that much of knowledge might not be enough to program with unity. Can I jump directly to graphics in C#, learn more about control structures, data types, functions, and looping or is there more I need to learn about in order to make my own basic game in Unity 3d? What kinda concepts do I basically need to know in C# to program in Unity? My current knowledge in C# is simply too basic.

Comment: Pretty sure you can use JS to program in Unity

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Comment: As you are not doing anything that is a danger to yourself or others - you can carry on and do exactly that. People trying something that is beyond their current capabilities is the way civilisation has advanced. This project seems to be for your own benefit, rather than a paid job, so it is possibly a good way of learning. If you do get stuck - then try your hardest to find out why - and failing all else come back here with specific questions showing the code that you have tried to date. Best of luck.

Comment: As others have mentioned, yes, you need a decent grasp of C# (or UnityScript). There's a very good, free C# course on Microsoft Virtual Academy here: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-16169?l=Lvld4EQIC_2706218949

Comment: +1 to @PaulF comment.  Use this as a learning opportunity.  You have to know some programming for Unity... so either learn the Javascript stuff, or C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Unity, you user either C# or UnityScript (A sort of JavaScript variant) for programming game logic, and Cg (Very similar to HLSL) for shaders. If you want to spend some money, though, you can also get node based programming tools (Sort of like Unreal Engine 4's Blueprints) from the Unity Asset Store for both.

As for actual concepts, knowing most of the general use aspects of C# is a must (The different loops, Lists and Dictionaries etc), but you also need to learn that Unity has added some things of it's own like [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), as well as the fact that Unity is a game engine and how game engine flow works (ie, don't put a loop in the Update method that runs for a long time or the entire game will lag, etc). Reading up on component based architectures is also important, as instead of just having one class per game object, you can have multiple components. This way, you can say add a behaviour (Unity's name for a component) that gives something the ability to pathfind, and another that gives that same object the ability to shoot at the player, etc.

Finally, have a look at Unity's documentation on [serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html). Serialization is extremely important in many aspects of Unity, including recompiling your code without restarting the editor, as well as saving/loading and networking if you want to get into such things. It's handy to know how this works though to make sure what you're doing is both efficient and that the engine is treating your data how you expect it to do.